# Can't Launch Unreal Engine 4 in Arch Linux

Tags: c++, archlinux, unreal-engine4

I am having an annoying problem while launching unreal-engine. I installed it from the AUR, the game is installed in directory /opt/unreal-engine. Here is the log messages. I am still a beginner on both linux and unreal-engine, so guide me with easy to follow steps. Thanks.

```
    LogUnixPlatformFile: Warning: create dir('/opt/unreal-engine/Engine/Saved/Config/Linux/Manifest.ini') failed: errno=13 (Permission denied)
    LogUnixPlatformFile: Warning: create dir('/opt/unreal-engine/Engine/Saved/Config/Linux/Manifest.ini') failed: errno=13 (Permission denied)
    LogUnixPlatformFile: Warning: create dir('/opt/unreal-engine/Engine/Saved/Config/CrashReportClient/UE4CC-Linux-F9CC0BA4D1E046998DB4DD29DC904FC3/CrashReportClient.ini') failed: errno=13 (Permission denied)
    LogUnixPlatformFile: Warning: create dir('/opt/unreal-engine/Engine/Saved/Config/CrashReportClient/UE4CC-Linux-F9CC0BA4D1E046998DB4DD29DC904FC3/CrashReportClient.ini') failed: errno=13 (Permission denied)
    [2020.02.05-06.48.13:587][  0]LogUnixPlatformFile: Warning: open('/opt/unreal-engine/Engine/DerivedDataCache/8729777EB19D4DDAA2910A8040E24FC5.tmp', Flags=0x00080041) failed: errno=13 (Permission denied)
[2020.02.05-06.48.13:587][  0]LogUnixPlatformFile: Warning: open('/opt/unreal-engine/Engine/DerivedDataCache/8729777EB19D4DDAA2910A8040E24FC5.tmp', Flags=0x00080041) failed: errno=13 (Permission denied)
[2020.02.05-06.48.13:587][  0]LogDerivedDataCache: Warning: Fail to write to ../../../Engine/DerivedDataCache, derived data cache to this directory will be read only. WriteError: 0 (errno=2 (No such file or directory)) ReadError: 0 (errno=2 (No such file or directory))
[2020.02.05-06.48.13:587][  0]LogDerivedDataCache: Warning: Local data cache path (../../../Engine/DerivedDataCache) was not usable, will not use it.
[2020.02.05-06.48.13:587][  0]LogDerivedDataCache: Unable to find inner node Local for hierarchical cache Hierarchy.
[2020.02.05-06.48.13:587][  0]LogDerivedDataCache: Shared data cache path not found in *engine.ini, will not use an Shared cache.
[2020.02.05-06.48.13:587][  0]LogDerivedDataCache: Unable to find inner node Shared for hierarchical cache Hierarchy.
[2020.02.05-06.48.13:612][  0]LogMaterial: Verifying Global Shaders for SF_VULKAN_SM5
Fatal error: [File:/home/utkarsha/Applications/unreal-engine/src/unreal-engine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/ShaderCompiler/ShaderCompiler.cpp] [Line: 1253] 
Could not create the shader compiler transfer file '/opt/unreal-engine/Engine/Intermediate/Shaders/tmp/DD11AF6A45C44C8586192EE55DBE07C0/0A2ADC10248884539A8A1054157AD3D00'.
Signal 11 caught.
Malloc Size=65538 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=65554 
CommonUnixCrashHandler: Signal=11
Malloc Size=65535 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=131119 
Malloc Size=439632 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=570768 
Malloc Size=330840 LargeMemoryPoolOffset=901624 
[2020.02.05-06.48.37:669][  0]LogCore: === Critical error: ===
Unhandled Exception: SIGSEGV: invalid attempt to write memory at address 0x0000000000000003

[2020.02.05-06.48.37:669][  0]LogCore: Fatal error: [File:/home/utkarsha/Applications/unreal-engine/src/unreal-engine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/ShaderCompiler/ShaderCompiler.cpp] [Line: 1253] 
Could not create the shader compiler transfer file '/opt/unreal-engine/Engine/Intermediate/Shaders/tmp/DD11AF6A45C44C8586192EE55DBE07C0/0A2ADC10248884539A8A1054157AD3D00'.
0x00007f76dd8d93f0 libUE4Editor-Engine.so!FShaderCompileThreadRunnable::CompilingLoop() [/home/utkarsha/Applications/unreal-engine/src/unreal-engine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/ShaderCompiler/ShaderCompiler.cpp:1513]
0x00007f76dd8d45a9 libUE4Editor-Engine.so!FShaderCompileThreadRunnableBase::Run() [/home/utkarsha/Applications/unreal-engine/src/unreal-engine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/ShaderCompiler/ShaderCompiler.cpp:1078]
0x00007f76e0202167 libUE4Editor-Core.so!FRunnableThreadPThread::Run() [/home/utkarsha/Applications/unreal-engine/src/unreal-engine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/HAL/PThreadRunnableThread.cpp:25]
0x00007f76e01c9a00 libUE4Editor-Core.so!FRunnableThreadPThread::_ThreadProc(void*) [/home/utkarsha/Applications/unreal-engine/src/unreal-engine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/HAL/PThreadRunnableThread.h:177]
0x00007f76e0cc54cf libpthread.so.0!UnknownFunction(0x94ce)
0x00007f76d7a792d3 libc.so.6!clone(+0x42)





0x00007f76e0197af6 libUE4Editor-Core.so!FGenericPlatformMisc::RaiseException(unsigned int) [/home/utkarsha/Applications/unreal-engine/src/unreal-engine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/GenericPlatform/GenericPlatformMisc.cpp:477]
0x00007f76e03abd97 libUE4Editor-Core.so!FOutputDevice::LogfImpl(char16_t const*, ...) [/home/utkarsha/Applications/unreal-engine/src/unreal-engine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/Misc/OutputDevice.cpp:71]
0x00007f76dd8d5b15 libUE4Editor-Engine.so!FShaderCompileThreadRunnable::WriteNewTasks() [/home/utkarsha/Applications/unreal-engine/src/unreal-engine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/ShaderCompiler/ShaderCompiler.cpp:1253]
0x00007f76dd8d93f0 libUE4Editor-Engine.so!FShaderCompileThreadRunnable::CompilingLoop() [/home/utkarsha/Applications/unreal-engine/src/unreal-engine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/ShaderCompiler/ShaderCompiler.cpp:1513]
0x00007f76dd8d45a9 libUE4Editor-Engine.so!FShaderCompileThreadRunnableBase::Run() [/home/utkarsha/Applications/unreal-engine/src/unreal-engine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/ShaderCompiler/ShaderCompiler.cpp:1078]
0x00007f76e0202167 libUE4Editor-Core.so!FRunnableThreadPThread::Run() [/home/utkarsha/Applications/unreal-engine/src/unreal-engine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/HAL/PThreadRunnableThread.cpp:25]
0x00007f76e01c9a00 libUE4Editor-Core.so!FRunnableThreadPThread::_ThreadProc(void*) [/home/utkarsha/Applications/unreal-engine/src/unreal-engine/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/HAL/PThreadRunnableThread.h:177]
0x00007f76e0cc54cf libpthread.so.0!UnknownFunction(0x94ce)
0x00007f76d7a792d3 libc.so.6!clone(+0x42)

[2020.02.05-06.48.37:669][  0]LogExit: Executing StaticShutdownAfterError
Engine crash handling finished; re-raising signal 11 for the default handler. Good bye.
fish: “./UE4Editor” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Comment: By looking at the logs, UE4 does not have a permission to write in the place where it was installed/is launched. My guess is, try lunching it with admin rights, or change installation directory to somewhere where it does not need these rights.

Comment: thanks it worked, i changed the directory but now the unreal editor is stuck at 18% "verifying Global Shaders for SF_VULKAN_SM5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Utkarsha Khanal. Waiting simply fixed it for me, It took about 10-20mins on "verifying Global Shaders for SF_VULKAN_SM5" and then it booted up fine and compiled the shaders. Give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. solved by changing folder permission. sync unreal want to not run as sudo, you have to make a change on folder permission first.